# How to center a span vertically inside a h1 background

Tags: css

I have a `span` inside a `h1` and I would like to center it vertically in the `h1` background.

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
}
span {
    font-size: 8.5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title <span>i</span></h1>
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align: middle;` and `margin-top: -5px;` to your `span`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align:middle;` to it's styles:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
}
span {
    font-size: 8.5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title <span>i</span></h1>
```

If that isn't central enough (it can be based on you font size), you can use flex for true centering - the following also centres the i in the circle:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  
  /*add this*/
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
span {
    font-size: 8.5px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    /*use this for vertical centering*/
    align-self:center;
    
    /*use this to center the i*/
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title <span>i</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use equal `height` and `width` property with `border-radius` to get proper circle and remove `padding-left`

You can use flex for it and update css as i posted below

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  font-size: 8.5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title <span>i</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  position:relative;
}
span {
    font-size: 8.5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(0,-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Title <span>i</span></h1>
```